# AWS - How to use a Public VIF?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to work through some misunderstandings and misinformation about VIFs and accessing AWS from on-prem systems. Needless to say, I've done a lot of reading of the docs, but can't get to the answers I need.

We have an on-prem site connected to AWS via Direct Connects. We have Private VIFs connecting to VPC in AWS, and all this is working fine and seems to be reasonably well understood by everyone.

We have some knowledge gaps about Public VIFs though. We've created them successfully enough, they have a VLAN ID and a have router peer IPs. However, I'm unclear how we actually use them. That is, if I'm sitting on an on-prem server and want to make an AWS API call to (say) S3 or DynamoDB or something, how do I ensure the request goes via the Public VIF and not just out via the Internet?

I'm trying to give our architects, devops/sysadmins and networks teams the information they need to configure things up for this (and experimenting until I get it working isn't much of an option because of bureaucracy), so any clues would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to answer my own question - not sure if I'm correct or not though.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/control-routes-direct-connect/ suggests that the public VIF advertises routes to the different API endpoints. This suggests that if my machine is connected to a network, and my default router knows about these routes, that it'll automatically route the API requests I make to the public VIF rather than send them to it's default route, which would be the Internet.